# The Two Eilenberg-Moores

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory

So, there is the Eilenberg-Moore spectral sequence, and there is (for any monad $(T,\mu,\eta)$ on a category $C$) the Eilenberg-Moore Category $C^T$ of $T$-algebras.

The silly question, is the very-general latter thing at all helpful in thinking about the fairly specific former thing? Or do they just happen to be attributed to the same two people?

Comment: I'm fairly sure they just happen to be invented by the same people...